# Cannot start multiple instances of Pending Intent despite using different ID

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'll give a background of what I am trying to achieve. In my activity, I'm using Alarm Manager to send a Pending Intent to a Broadcast receiver (**'NotificationBroadcastReceiver'**), whose task is to show notifications. When the user taps on the action buttons (SNOOZE and POSTPONE), it sends a Broadcast to another receiver (**'NotificationActionReceiver'**), which then performs the appropriate action - If it is postpone, it sends an Alarm some time later to send a broadcast to **'NotificationBroadcastReceiver'** (so that the **SAME** notification can be shown).

This is where the problem is. The **DONE** and **POSTPONE** actions are running on 2 different Pending Intents, and although I am providing them different arguments, only the one for the Postpone gets fired. Where did I did the mistake?

**NotificationBroadcastReceiver:**

```
package com.coffeetech.kittycatch;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Build;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

public class NotificationBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int type; // 0 for Daily reminder, 1 for Shopping reminder
        type = intent.getIntExtra("reminder", -1);

        //below code for action
        Intent postponeIntent, doneIntent;
        PendingIntent postponePendingIntent, donePendingIntent;

        postponeIntent = new Intent(context,NotificationActionReceiver.class);
        postponeIntent.setAction("postpone");
        postponeIntent.putExtra("type",type);

        doneIntent = new Intent(context,NotificationActionReceiver.class);
        postponeIntent.setAction("done");
        doneIntent.putExtra("type",type);

        //MAYBE THE PROBLEM IS IN THE BELOW 2 LINES
        postponePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,3,postponeIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        donePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,4,doneIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);



        //below code for user tap on notification
        Intent reminderIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        reminderIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, reminderIntent, 0);
        String title, text;

        switch (type) {
            case 0: //FOR EVERYDAY NOTIFICATIONS
                title = "Daily Reminder";
                text = "Time to update the quantities";
                break;
            case 1: //BELOW CODE TO MAKE AND SHOW SHOPPING NOTIFICATION
                title = "Shopping Reminder";
                text = "You need to buy certain things!";
                break;
            default:
                title = "ERROR";
                text = "in the Broadcast Receiver";
        }

        try {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "kitty catch notification")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .setAllowSystemGeneratedContextualActions(false)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_REMINDER)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getPackageManager().getResourcesForApplication("com.coffeetech.kittycatch"), R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground))
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_snooze, "POSTPONE", postponePendingIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_done, "DONE", donePendingIntent);

            // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
            notificationManager.notify(type, builder.build());

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**NotificationActionReceiver:**

```
package com.coffeetech.kittycatch;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

public class NotificationActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        int type = intent.getIntExtra("type", -1);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

        //remove existing notification
        notificationManager.cancel(type);

        if(action == "done"){
            if(type == 1) {
                Intent doneIntent = new Intent("reset");
                doneIntent.putExtra("reset", true);
                context.sendBroadcast(doneIntent);
            }
        }else{
            Intent snoozeIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationBroadcastReceiver.class);
            snoozeIntent.putExtra("reminder", type);
            snoozeIntent.setAction("another notification");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = null;
            //try {
                //pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.createPackageContext("com.coffeetech.kittycatch",0), 8, snoozeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 8, snoozeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            //} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
              //  e.printStackTrace();
            //}
            int minutes = 1;
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + minutes * 60000, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every pending intent needs an action:

```
broadcastIntent.setAction("button1");
```

Inside you broadcast receiver you can catch the intent with intent.getaction().

Hope this helps.